# Generate log4j xml configuration from gradle

Tags: gradle, log4j2

Is there any way to configure log4j2 directly form build.gradle file in a gradle project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the xml config file at build time using groovy's MarkupBuilder.
Sample task that generates the default configuration and palces it on the resources folder (if you don't have one, make sure to create it):

```
task generateLog4jConfig{
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer) 

    xml.Configuration(status: 'WARN') {
        Appenders{
            Console(name: 'Console', target: 'SYSTEM_OUT'){
                PatternLayout(patern: '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n')
            }
        } 
        Loggers{
            Root(level: 'error'){
                AppenderRef(ref: 'Console')
            }
        }       
    }
    def xmlFile = file('src/main/resources/log4j2.xml')
    xmlFile.delete()
    xmlFile.write(writer.toString())
}
```

You can make your build task depend on it and therefore be sure that your config xml will always be consistent with the contents of your gradle file.